# 1С 8.3. Откуда в этой строке запроса берутся параметры?

Tags: 1с

1С 8.3. Откуда в этой строке запроса берутся параметры:

```
РегистрНакопления.ДоходыИРасходы.Обороты(,,,,);
```

Можно ли самому назначить количество параметров, или это фиксированный?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не забывайте, что у вас есть встроенная справка (F1) и синтакс-помощник (Ctrl+Shift+F1).

[image: Выдержка из справки]

Если параметры виртуальной таблицы не указаны, они заполняются значениями по-умолчанию. **Количество параметров виртуальной таблицы фиксированное!**

Список полезных ссылок для изучения:

1. [ИТС - Устройство регистра накопления](https://its.1c.ru/db/metod8dev/content/2726/hdoc)
2. [Запросы и виртуальные таблицы](https://www.koderline.ru/expert/instruktsii/article-ispolzovanie-virtualnykh-tablits-1s-v-zaprosakh/)