# 1C 8.3. Откуда в запросе у регистров берутся поля, которых нет в дереве конфигурации?

Tags: 1с

Есть такой запрос:

```
Запрос = Новый Запрос;
    Запрос.Текст = "ВЫБРАТЬ
   | СправочникНоменклатуры.Наименование, 
   | СправочникНоменклатуры.Ссылка,
   | СправочникНоменклатуры.Артикул,
   | СправочникНоменклатуры.Код,
   | ЕСТЬNULL(УчетНоменклатурыОстатки.КоличествоОстаток, 0) КАК КоличествоОстаток
|ИЗ                           
   | Справочник.Номенклатура КАК СправочникНоменклатуры
   |     ЛЕВОЕ СОЕДИНЕНИЕ РегистрНакопления.ОстаткиТоваровКомпании.Остатки КАК УчетНоменклатурыОстатки
   |     ПО УчетНоменклатурыОстатки.Номенклатура = СправочникНоменклатуры.Ссылка
|ГДЕ
  |  СправочникНоменклатуры.ЭтоГруппа = ЛОЖЬ И СправочникНоменклатуры.СкрытьЭлемент = Истина";
```

Есть поле: `УчетНоменклатурыОстатки.КоличествоОстаток` (Полностью: `РегистрНакопления.ОстаткиТоваровКомпании.Остатки.КоличествоОстаток`).
Это поле существует, но в дереве конфигурации нет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Где его смотреть? (его структуру)

Answer (score 0):

Если `РегистрНакопления` имеет вид *Остатки*, тогда у него доступна виртуальная таблица Остатки ; К которой обращение выглядит РегистрНакопления.ОстаткиТоваровКомпании.**Остатки**

В этом случае можно получить Остаток по любому Ресурсу регистра, УчетНоменклатурыОстатки.Количество**Остаток**

P.S. более аккуратно получать Остатки на конкретную дату, и по определенным позициям
https://its.1c.ru/db/pubqlang#content:98:hdoc

Answer (score 0):

Вчера отвечал вам на [ваш вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1498238/1%D0%A1-8-3-%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B), про параметры виртуальных таблиц. Настоятельно советую почитать ссылки из моего ответа и разобраться в работе виртуальных таблиц.